# Unable to Control NVIDIA Fan Speed

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, fan, xserver

[NVIDIA X Server Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Uk9.jpg)

In NVIDIA X Server Settings it is showing: `Failed to set new Fan Speed`
From terminal I have tried the following command:

```
nvidia-settings -a GPUFanControlState=1 -a GPUTargetFanSpeed=60
```

Which is showing the **error**:

```
  Attribute 'GPUFanControlState' (GTX1660:1[gpu:0]) assigned value 1.


ERROR: Error assigning value 60 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' (GTX1660:1[fan:0]) as specified in
       assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=60' (Unknown Error).


ERROR: Error assigning value 60 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' (GTX1660:1[fan:1]) as specified in
       assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=60' (Unknown Error).
```

`nvidia-smi` details:

```
Wed Jun  1 11:49:20 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.73.05    Driver Version: 510.73.05    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 26%   37C    P8    15W / 125W |    360MiB /  6144MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1100      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 35MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1616      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                116MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1741      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               38MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2096      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          159MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3355      G   /usr/bin/nvidia-settings            0MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved this issue by editing the file: `/./etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`
Steps:

1. `cd /./etc/X11/`
2. `sudo -s` [because you need root access]
3. `gedit Xwrapper.config &`
4. add the line `needs_root_rights=yes` before `allowed_users=console`.
5. Reboot your machine

Therefore the `Xwrapper.config` file will be:

```
# Xwrapper.config (Debian X Window System server wrapper configuration file)
#
# This file was generated by the post-installation script of the
# xserver-xorg-legacy package using values from the debconf database.
#
# See the Xwrapper.config(5) manual page for more information.
#
# This file is automatically updated on upgrades of the xserver-xorg-legacy
# package *only* if it has not been modified since the last upgrade of that
# package.
#
# If you have edited this file but would like it to be automatically updated
# again, run the following command as root:
#   dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-legacy
needs_root_rights=yes
allowed_users=console
```

Comment: In 2023, I had to reboot for this solution to work. It does work, though.

Comment: Okay, I've also included the reboot step in the instructions.

Comment: Mah boi, thanks :)